# I want use edit text with cross button,but when I'm trying to enter the text my text is going on the top of the button

Tags: android

I want use edit text with cross button,but when I'm trying to enter the text my text is going on the top of the button

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="9dp"
    android:padding="5dp">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        [![enter image description here][1]][1]android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:textSize="25dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:hint="hi"
        android:singleLine="true" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_gravity="right|center_vertical"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_action" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

put the button before the editText, in a framelayout whichever is the first child will be at the top of all the other children so what you need to do is this,

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="9dp"
    android:padding="5dp">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_gravity="right|center_vertical"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_action" />
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        [![enter image description here][1]][1]android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:textSize="25dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:hint="hi"
        android:singleLine="true" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: it is still doing the same thing

Comment: no after making this change the button will be on top and the text will appear behind it.. what exactly are you looking for here?

Answer (score 0):

Multiple children inside a FrameLayout might overlap across different screen sizes  (see [FrameLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/FrameLayout.html)), try using another parent layout like RelativeLayout, Or LinearLayout.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the suggestions provided:

You can also try to use `android:layout_below`